# Contracting a Vector with Multiple Scalar Products

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix $\textbf{A}$ (ie. a second rank tensor) and then contract with a vector $\textbf{v}$, I will get a new vector.

Now the situation I have is a scalar product of 3 matrices $\textbf{A} \cdot \textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{C}$, so if I want to now contract (or dot) this whole product with the vector $\textbf{v}$, do I need to contract $\textbf{v}$ with each matrix in turn and then do the scalar product of the 3 matrices with the result $(\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{A}) \cdot (\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{B}) \cdot (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{C})$?

Comment: what do you mean by "contract"?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi by 'contract' I mean 'dot' or do the matrix multiplication if you want to see it that way, so you multiply the row vector into the matrix to get another vector.  Basically I am asking if you dot the scalar product of 3 matrices with a vector, do you get the result I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "scalar product" is so called because it's supposed to produce a scalar; that is, a single number, not a matrix. And it's usually only defined between two vectors, not between general matrices. "Dot product" is synonymous. "Tensor contraction" is similar, but more general.

I assume you mean the ordinary matrix product: $A\cdot B\cdot C=ABC$. The product of this with a row vector $v$ is simply $\,vABC\,$. Note that we don't need parentheses, because matrix multiplication is associative, unlike the dot product. In fact, something like $(u\cdot v)\cdot w$ is undefined, because $(u\cdot v)$ is a scalar, not a vector.

The tensor product of two matrices, $\,A\otimes B=T\,$, is a 4-dimensional array, with components $\,T_{i,j,k,l}=A_{i,j}B_{k,l}\,$. (That's ordinary multiplication of numbers.) The matrix product $AB$ is a contraction of the tensor $T$, with components

$$(AB)_{i,l}=\sum_j T_{i,j,j,l}=\sum_j A_{i,j}B_{j,l}.$$

Comment: Yes, I just meant ordinary matrix multiplication, the notation in the paper I am reading was just confusing me (it uses non-standard notation for some reason).